# Linked List removing duplicate from list, reference confusion

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

I'm having trouble understanding how this method below removes the duplicates in the linked list. After calling this method, all duplicates are successfully removed. Why is the head not null? Wouldnt the head node be null because the current variable in the method iterated to the end. How does this method successfully update the list to get rid of the duplicate items?

```
 static void removeDuplicate(node head) 
{
    // Hash to store seen values
    HashSet<Integer> hs = new HashSet<>();

    node current = head; 
    node prev = null;
    while (current != null) 
    {
        int curval = current.val;

         // If current value is seen before
        if (hs.contains(curval)) {
            prev.next = current.next;
        } else {
            hs.add(curval);
            prev = current;
        }
        current = current.next;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Elements get removed by changing the pointer from the **previous element** to point to the **next element**. That is how you remove elements in `LinkedList`s, by skipping them. The garbage collector will later remove the object as no object refers to it anymore.

Here is an illustration of the removal:

[image: Illustration]

---

Duplicates are **identified** by memorizing each encountered value in a `HashSet`. If you find an element which was already **encountered before** (i.e. contained in the set), it is a **duplicate**.

---

The `head` can not get `null` because it was not `null` previously and duplicates can only occur **after the first element**, since you need to encounter an element at least once until you can find a duplicate. For example a list like `[1, 1, 1]` gets modified to `[1]` and not to `[]`.

Also the variable `head` gets not changed in the method, it points to the head-node before and after the method. It seems that you got confused by `current = head` but you need to know that this, in Java, does **not synchronize** both variables. If the method changes `current` this changes are **not** reflected by `head`. The statement just means '*let `current` point to where `head` points*' and afterwards you let `current` point elsewhere.

Comment: I understand that. However, what im having trouble with it is, `node current = head'. in the while loop we iterate until current is null. Wouldnt head also be null at the end off the loop?

Comment: `current == null` means we reached the end of the list, the **tail**. `current = head` means we start at the head. It does not link `head` to `current` such that changes on `current` also affect `head`. `head` itself will never be `null` by that method since it can not be a duplicate, duplicates can only occur after the first element (which is `head`). A list like `[1, 1, 1, 1]` will look like `[1]` after the method, not `[]`.